# Function does not take many inputs, and cannot plot correctly using Listplot

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I am a beginner with Mathematica.

I have a function which is defined as follows:

$h(x) = \begin{cases}
            \hfill \frac{1}{x}\sin(x) & \text{if $x\neq 0$}\\
                  1 & \text{if $x=0$}
            \end{cases}$

I want to produce a list plot of this function using `n=100` equally spaced points for `$x \in [0,2\pi]$`.

Here is my code for the fuction:

```
 h[x0_] :=
 Module[{x = x0},
  If[x != 2 \[Pi] != 0, x = Sin[x]/x, x = 1];
  x
  ]
```

and I have made my inputs as: `Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100]`

But I cannot evaluate the function at every 100 points separately, it returns me the inputs.

I want to plot this using "Listplot" and display it with a dotted Magenta line.

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: have you tried `ListPlot[h /@ Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100]]` or `ListPlot[Maph]@ Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100]]`?

Comment: Note that your `h[x]` is just `Sinc[x]`

Comment: `ListPlot[h /@ Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 100], PlotStyle -> Magenta]` ?

Comment: @cvgmt - You should include the option `DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi}`

Comment: Set attribute `Listable ` to your function h. `h[x0_] := Module[{x = x0}, If[x != 2 \[Pi] != 0, x = Sin[x]/x, x = 1];
  x]; SetAttributes[h, Listable]; h[Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100]] `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bob already pointed out, the function `h[x]` you're interested in is already available as [`Sinc`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sinc.html). However, if you do want to define it yourself, you could have created a piecewise function like that:

```
h[x_] := Piecewise[{{1/x*Sin[x], x != 0}}, 1];
```

Now, you need a list of 100 equidistant points in the interval [0, 2Pi] and there are many ways to achieve this. If you look closely at your `Range` call, you'll note that you're not creating exactly 100 points but 101. More intuitive is to use

```
Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 100]
```

because you can input the number of points you want to have instead of the stepsize. Having said all this, here are some ways to create a list of data values you want to plot

```
xvals = Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 100];
data1 = Map[h, xvals];
data2 = h /@ xvals;
data3 = Sinc /@ xvals;
data4 = Sinc[xvals];
```

To visualize this with a "dotted magenta _line" you could use [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) and display the mesh points:

```
ListLinePlot[data1,
 PlotStyle -> Magenta,
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.011]}
 ]
```

[image]